# Animating UIScrollView with paging

Tags: ios, animation, uiscrollview, scroll-paging

I am having a scrollView having 2 subviews per screen and thus 10 subviews.Paging is disabled right now. Now i want whenever I swipe up the subviews inside scrollviews, they should fill the entire screen and after then, normal scrolling is applicable having 10 views each on one screen with paging enabled.Any help??

```
const NSUInteger kNumViews= 10;
const CGFloat vScrollObjWidth   = 160.0;
const CGFloat vScrollObjHeight  = 280.0;

- (void)layoutScrollViews
{
 UIView *view = nil;
 NSArray *subviews = [scrollView2 subviews];
  CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
    for (view in subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view.tag > 0)
        {
            CGRect frame = view.frame;
            frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
            view.frame = frame;

            curXLoc += (vScrollObjWidth);
        }
    }


    [scrollView2 setContentSize:CGSizeMake((kNumViews+1) * vScrollObjWidth, scrollView2.bounds.size.height)];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor viewFlipsideBackgroundColor];
    scrollView2.delegate = self;
    [scrollView2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    scrollView2.scrollEnabled = YES;

    for (i = 1; i <= kNumViews; i++)
    {
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"imageV%d.jpg", i];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        [imageView sizeToFit];
        imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;

        CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
        rect.size.height = vScrollObjHeight;
        rect.size.width = vScrollObjWidth;
        imageView.frame = rect;
        imageView.tag = i;
            imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        [scrollView2 addSubview:imageView];

    }
    [self layoutScrollViews];

    self.swipeRecognizerUp = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scaleMove:)];
    [self.swipeRecognizerUp setDelegate:self];
    [scrollView2 addGestureRecognizer:self.swipeRecognizerUp];

    self.swipeRecognizerDown = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scaleDown:)];
    [self.swipeRecognizerDown setDelegate:self];
    [scrollView2 addGestureRecognizer:self.swipeRecognizerDown];
    self.swipeRecognizerDown.enabled = NO;



}

-(void)scaleMove:(id)sender {

    [[[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender view] layer] removeAllAnimations];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[sender view]];

    CGPoint velocity = [sender velocityInView:self.view];
    if(abs(velocity.y) - abs(velocity.x) > 500 && velocity.y < 0){
        CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 0.82);
        CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,254);
        [sender view].transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, scale);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^(){
                         CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 1.64);
                         CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,-254);
                         [sender view].transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, scale);

                    }
                     completion:nil];

    scrollView2.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.swipeRecognizerDown.enabled = YES;
    self.swipeRecognizerUp.enabled = NO;
    }
    }



-(void)scaleDown:(id)sender {
    [[[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender view] layer] removeAllAnimations];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[sender view]];
    CGPoint velocity = [sender velocityInView:self.view];
    if(abs(velocity.y) - abs(velocity.x) > 500 && velocity.y > 0){
        [sender view].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 1.64);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^(){
                         [sender view].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 0.82);
                     }
                     completion:nil];
    scrollView2.pagingEnabled = NO;
    self.swipeRecognizerUp.enabled = YES;
    self.swipeRecognizerDown.enabled = NO;
    }

}
```

Comment: Add some code as to what you have thus far and where you're having issues.

Comment: right now, i am doing this kind of thing.scaling whole scrollview in order to fit entire screen by one view only and then enabling paging but in this way it is skipping every alternate page.